# How do I insert an image in XML?

Tags: xml, image, xslt

I'm in the process of learning XML and am currently doing an assignment that involves me creating XML & XSLT for a catalogue. I've managed to insert images into this catalogue using XSLT however have just been made aware I need to insert the image into the XML instead, looking for some insight on how to do this?

Comment: What output format do you intend to generate via XSLT? HTML5? XSL-FO?

Comment: It'll need to generate HTML5

Comment: What XML vocabulary  are you using? DocBook? Or DITA? TEI? Or your own format?